# Using BufferedReader to input a character

Tags: java

BufferedReader can be used to input integers, floats and so on

```
import java.io.*;

public class Wrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int h = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    }

}
```

Is there any way to enter characters using it?

Comment: `BufferedReader` can be used to input *text*. Nothing else. What you do with the text afterwards, such as parsing it into integers, floats, etc., has nothing to do with `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Ok, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code

```
public class Wrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         char c = (char)br.read();
         System.out.println(c);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use the [read](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_read_char.htm) method

```
 private static void handleCharacters(Reader reader)
            throws IOException {
        int r;
        while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) r;
            //process
        }
}
```

Here is how you can accumulate the chars in an array of size 100.

```
     char charArray[] = new char[ 100 ];
     int i = 0;
     BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     int c = 0;
     while((c = buffer.read()) != -1 && i < 100) {
          char character = (char) c;
          charArray[i++] = c;
     }
     System.out.println(charArray);
```

Comment: I am unable to print the value of ch outside the while loop or maybe i Am doing it wrong. Could you show it to me?

Comment: char ch is inside the scope of while loop and hence inaccessible outside the loop.  Are you trying to accumulate the chars entered? In that case, you can have a char array of the expected length.

Comment: declare the char ch outside the while loop.

Comment: @AnilCk that wouldn't make much sense as ch will just store the last char entered

Comment: @rahulroc yes you are correct, It stores only the last value entered

Answer (score 1):

```
char a=br.readLine().charAt(0);
```

Comment: This really  could do with some explanation of why it is the correct answer.